# Calling a snowflake procedure from Talend throws an unexpected exception/warning

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, talend

I'm trying to call a Snowflake procedure directly out of an ETL process in Talend.
I'm using the `tSnowflakeRow` component since there is no dedicated component for calling Snowflake procedures as we would do for other DB types in Talend.

In the screenshot below, you can see that calling the procedure directly in Snowflake's preview app works well…

[image: PreviewAppSnowflake]

Nevertheless, calling it from Talend throws the following exception:

```
[WARN ]: org.talend.components.snowflake.runtime.SnowflakeRowReader - Query execution failed. Record was not processed.
net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLException: Stored procedure execution error: Scoped transaction started in stored procedure is incomplete and it was rolled back.
Row 1: Stored procedure execution error: Scoped transaction started in stored procedure is incomplete and it was rolled back.
```

The interesting line being

- `Row 1: Stored procedure execution error: Scoped transaction started in stored procedure is incomplete and it was rolled back.`

**Here's the DDL of my procedure:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "CALCULATEDURATIONFORDESIGNAABACUS"()
RETURNS VARCHAR(16777216)
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS '
var query1 = 
`
  INSERT INTO durations (id, odb_created_at, event_id_arrival, event_id_departure,
  event_time_arrival, event_time_departure,
  card_nr, ticket_type, duration, manufacturer, carpark_id)

  WITH cte AS (
      SELECT e.id, e.card_nr, e.event_time, e.ticket_type, e.manufacturer, e.carpark_id, e.device_type,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY e.card_nr, e.carpark_id, e.event_time, e.device_type) AS rn
      FROM events e
      LEFT JOIN durations d ON d.event_id_arrival = e.id OR d.event_id_departure = e.id
      WHERE e.event_time >= (SELECT PROP_VALUE::timestamp FROM properties WHERE prop_key = ''DURATION.LIMIT.DATE'')
      AND e.device_type IN (1, 2)
      AND event_type = 2
      AND e.manufacturer LIKE ''DESIGNA_ABACUS%''
      AND d.id IS NULL
  )
  SELECT 
    durationseq.nextval,
    current_timestamp(),
    arrived_entry.id,
    departed_entry.id,
    arrived_entry.event_time,
    departed_entry.event_time,
    arrived_entry.card_nr,
    arrived_entry.ticket_type,
    timestampdiff(second, arrived_entry.event_time, departed_entry.event_time),
    arrived_entry.manufacturer,
    arrived_entry.carpark_id
  FROM (SELECT * FROM cte WHERE cte.device_type = 1) AS arrived_entry
  INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM cte WHERE cte.device_type = 2) AS departed_entry 
    ON arrived_entry.card_nr = departed_entry.card_nr
  AND arrived_entry.carpark_id = departed_entry.carpark_id
  AND arrived_entry.rn + 1 = departed_entry.rn
`;

snowflake.execute({ sqlText: query1 });

var query2 = "SELECT PROP_VALUE FROM properties WHERE prop_key = ''DURATION.LIMIT.DAYS''";
var stmt = snowflake.createStatement({ sqlText: query2 });
var resultSet = stmt.execute(); 
resultSet.next();
var prop_value = resultSet.getColumnValue(1); 

var query3 =
`
  UPDATE properties
  SET PROP_VALUE = (
    SELECT dateadd(day, -1 * ${prop_value}, MAX(event_time)) FROM events 
    WHERE event_time >= (
      SELECT PROP_VALUE::timestamp FROM properties WHERE prop_key = ''DURATION.LIMIT.DATE''
    )
  )
  WHERE PROP_KEY =''DURATION.LIMIT.DATE'';
`

stmt = snowflake.createStatement({ sqlText: query3 });
stmt.execute();

return ''true'';
';
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As you do not start a transaction explicitly inside the stored procedure, the issue should be related to AUTOCOMMIT. I suggest you check the samples of the scoped transactions:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/transactions.html#scoped-transactions

Maybe you disable AUTOCOMMIT, or Talend does it.

> When AUTOCOMMIT is off, be especially careful combining implicit
> transactions and stored procedures. If you accidentally leave a
> transaction active at the end of a stored procedure, the transaction
> is rolled back.
>
> For example, the following pseudo-code example causes an implicit
> ROLLBACK at the end of the stored procedure:

```
create procedure p1() ...
$$
    insert into parent_table ...;
    insert into child_table ...;
$$;


alter session set autocommit = false;
call p1; ----- this one will be rolled back
commit work;
```

Comment: Ok thank you, I understand what the problem is. I was not able to find a solution yet unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never :)

Add an explicit transaction start / commit / rollback into the sproc for it to execute nicely when autocommit is disabled, like this:

```
create procedure p1() ... 
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
$$
  snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: "BEGIN TRANSACTION"}).execute(); 
  -- insert into or whatever... 
  snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: "COMMIT"}).execute(); 
  return <what you need to return>;
$$;
```